# Creating a registry script

Tags: windows-7, windows

I am looking for some help in creating a registry script which can help me automate a job which I need to do to 20 HP Laptops.

Since imaging them, they work fine, however if a domain user other than administrator logs into one, it kicks them straight back out. 
I have found that the problem is linked to Ranger but the actual fault is a piece of redundant HP Bloatware which was removed before the imaging of the machine, but appears to still be lingering in the registry.

I need to change:
`HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\WinLogon Userinit` from: `C:\windows\SysWOW64\RgrUInit.exe,c:\Program Files (x86)\Hewlett-Packard\HP ProtectTools Security Manager\Bin\DPAgent.exe`

To:
`HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\WinLogon Userinit: C:\windows\SysWOW64\RgrUInit.exe,`

How can I quickly do this using a registry script?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

1. Open `regedit` on one of these machines.
2. Fix the issue.
3. Right-click a key that contains the value you have just modified.
4. Export it.
5. Open exported file in Notepad.
6. Remove everything except for INI section (`[name_of_exported_key]`) and entry for modified value (`name_of_modified_value=fixed_data`).
7. Save changes.
8. Distribute file to all machines and execute it. (to execute silently: `regedit /s file_name`)

Answer (score 2):

Basically, I know about two options you can use:

1. A `.reg` file

   - create a file with the *reg* extension name, and this data:

     > Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
     >
     > [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon]
     >   "Userinit"="INSERT_HERE_THE_CORRECT_VALUE"
   - Execute the file on each machine.
2. The `reg` command line

   > `reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v Userinit /d "INSERT_HERE_THE_CORRECT_VALUE"`